# python removing lines from file

Tags: python, regex, string, file, str-replace

**Question:**

I am trying to remove empty lines from my .txt files.
Because my .txt files are generated by Python through HTML download and i want to save them at a certain location, i have to use Os.path.join.

This is the code that saves the HTML on the location after removing all TAGS and keeping only the inside of the tags:

```
cntent = re.sub('<[^>]+>',"\n", str(cntent))
with open(os.path.join('/Users/Brian/Documents/test',titles), "wb") as file: 
        file.writelines(str(cntent))
```

how can i achieve this?

**The outcome of the file:**

```
Productspecificaties




Uiterlijke kenmerken















Gewicht










185 g
```

**What i tried:**

```
filtered = filter(lambda x: not re.match(r'^\s*$', x), original)
```

**Desired outcome**

```
 Productspecificaties
 Uiterlijke Kenmerken
 Gewicht
 185Gr
```

*Please note that in the first line of code `re.sub...` i use "\n" because otherwise there would be no spaces at all.*

Comment: Maybe something simple like `'\n'.join([line.strip() for line in cntent.split() if line.strip() != ''])`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expression:

```
cntent = re.sub('<[^>]+>',"\n", str(cntent))
with open(os.path.join('/Users/Brian/Documents/test', titles), "wb") as f: 
    f.writelines(line for line in cntent.splitlines(True) if line.strip())
```

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) strips spaces (includign newline) at the beginning and at the end of the string. For the line that consists of only spaces, it will return empty string; which is evaluated as false value.

[`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) with **True** was used to split lines, but not to exclude new lines.

Comment: apart from the indent you missed at `f.writelines` this code works! Thank you!

Comment: @user3671459, What do you mean I missed the indent?

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`,  now i got to figure out why not all of my files are formatted correctly but thats on me :)!

Answer (score -1):

try this pattern
`^\s+` w/ `m` option
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/43)